# how to create a custom JSON in C# and what should the return value be?

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net, ios, json

i want create a custom json data from the mssql 2008 results so that my iPhone could consume it.

i can consume json websites like this without a problem: 
[json link](http://www.colourlovers.com/api/colors?format=json)

the format could look like this:

```
Place: New York
       Hotel: Widget Hotel
       Telephone: 0305525253
```

which format should i return to consume it on the iPhone? an array a string, dictionary? i don't know

EDIT: here is my code:

```
    namespace WebService1
{
    public class LandHelper
    {
        internal static string[] Land()
        {
            List<string> landObject = new List<string>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT BEZEICHNUNG FROM LAND", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        if (rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            landObject.Add(rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return landObject.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

i tried this but i don't know how to add a key to the values i get from the database. 
i think it would be easier when i create a custom json format .

Comment: `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { Place= "New York", Hotel= "Widget Hotel",Telephone="0305525253"})`

Comment: a json string like `{"Place":"New York","Hotel":"Widget Hotel","Telephone":"0305525253"}` BTW, Why don't you try?

Comment: i edited my post. could you look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Return a List like

```
  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public List<StandortHelper.REGION> LAND()
    {
        return StandortHelper.LAND();
    }
```

You  can return easy a JSON-FORMAT

Answer (score 2):

*Okay, if I've understood this correctly what you're trying to do is stringify a collection of objects to JSON, and then read them in your iPhone app. I'm assuming you're asking for how to convert from `object-to-JSON`, and that you've already covered `JSON-to-object`. I'll cover `object-to-JSON` here.*

What you'll need to do is create a class that contains all of the information you need in your JSON file, like so.

```
public class Location
{
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Hotel { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

Now, inside your database reader statement, you'll want to construct a `List<Location>`, and then add each `Location` to this list. Once you've done this, you'll easily be able to convert the collection to JSON using the [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) framework... which makes converting objects to JSON as easy as:

```
// "locations" is the name of the collection
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(locations);
```

[JSON .NET Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)

Hope this helps. :)